# setFont Deprecated?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I get a warning saying that setFont is deprecated?

```
[button setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
```

Any suggestions how to take it away pls..

Answer (score 113, accepted):

As UIButton exposes its titleLabel starting from iPhone OS 3.0 you must set font to it directly:

```
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
```

Answer (score 11):

> Setting the font of the button directly is depracated in 3.x versions of the SDK. Instead, you need to set the properties of the button's titleLabel property.
>
> Code:
> `(mybutton).titleLabel.font =  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];`

Source: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/26126-warning-setting-font-button.html

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer works and sets the font for one button instance. In case you want to set application wide font for all UIButtons, you can do it like this:

```
// Set font to be used for labels inside UIButtons
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIButton class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:15.0]];
```

This was not specifically asked in the question, but in case you need to set the font for all labels (not inside UIButtons), you can do it like this:

```
// Set font for all UILabels
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0]];
```

Comment: This is a good idea.  sadly UILabel doesn't have the font property in the UIAppearance proxy and that's why the font doesn't work. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127921/appearance-proxy-not-working-as-intended-for-uibutton-font

Comment: @EvaMadrazo could you elaborate what doesn't work? I'm using the code above in my project and it's working fine. To get `appearanceWhenContainedIn` working with `UIButton` set the button type to `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

Comment: @EvaMadrazo oh, did you mean that the "Set font for all labels" doesn't work for `UIButton`s? That's true, I edited the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Yes, uilabel does not include setFont in the appearance proxy. So, [[UILabel appearance] setFont:..] has no effect.

Comment: @EvaMadrazo still, oddly enough i.e. [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiJ-Light" size:15]]; seems to work for me just fine.