# appearance proxy not working as intended for UIButton font

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiappearance

im currently styling my app via the appearance proxy and i ran into this problem:
when i set properties on the UIButton appearance my font is ignored:

```
[buttonAppearance setTitleColor:darkColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonAppearance.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:10.0]];
```

the first line is applied properly (darkColor is some UIColor), but my font change is ignored completely.
When i copy the line into my ViewController and apply it to a concrete button it works fine.

Am i missing something?

any help appreciated! ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font name is wrong, it should be `HelveticaNeue`, without the space between.

In the future if you want to see other iOS font names you should check [this website piece of code](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/)

**EDIT**

After a closer look I realized that you are trying to set the appearance of the button's title which is a `UILabel`, sadly `UILabel` doesn't have the font property in the  `UIAppearance` proxy and that's why the font doesn't work.

Comment: i guess not, because Helvetica Neue is the proper font family name, which defaults to the medium helvetica neue. even more important is the fact that it doesn't work when i change it to either @"HelveticaNeue-Light" or your @"HelveticaNeue" for the appearance proxy BUT all of them work when directly applied to a buttons title label. (with the exact same method call given above)

Comment: hmmm wierd - `ButtonAppearance.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontname size:13.0]]` definitely works on ios6.1.3 for me

Answer (score 1):

I have found this class [TWTButton.h](https://gist.github.com/d20337095c696330460e), who resolved my problems adding a new appearance selector [setTitleFont:] to the UIButton class.

```
buttonAppearance = [TWTButton appearance];
[buttonAppearance setTitleFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f]];
```

You may read more about this here : http://toastmo.com/blog/2013/01/17/uiappearance/