# How to change font of UIButton with Swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift, uifont

I am trying to change the font of a UIButton using Swift...

```
myButton.font = UIFont(name: "...", 10)
```

However `.font` is deprecated and I'm not sure how to change the font otherwise.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 554, accepted):

Use `titleLabel` instead. The `font` property is deprecated in iOS 3.0. It also does not work in Objective-C. `titleLabel` is label used for showing title on `UIButton`.

```
myButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 20)
```

However, while setting title text you should only use `setTitle:forControlState:`. Do not use `titleLabel` to set any text for title directly.

Comment: Do you guys know why I have to 'unwrap'? my label??  like this...   myButton.titleLabel!.font = ...

Comment: beacause `titleLabel` is optional property.Thanks previously in beta it was not.

Comment: This method allowed me to change my font name/style, but changing the size property made no difference.

Comment: You don't need to force unwrap the label. `myButton.titleLabel?.font = ...` will work since if titleLabel is nil it will just be a no-op

Comment: Why doe this method not work for custom UIbutton subclass?

Comment: I had some trouble finding my "YourfontName" specifically, until I found this list of all the names: https://gist.github.com/tadija/cb4ec0cbf0a89886d488d1d8b595d0e9  .    There's ways to get them spit out programmatically, but I've lost that code since I implemented it a few years ago, if I find it I will post it here (used it to grab a custom font name).

Comment: @Munib I have. How did you solve that?

Answer (score 107):

As mentioned by many here you can set the font with something like:

```
button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 19.0, weight: .bold)
```

Just make sure your button has `default` style though for this to be applicable, otherwise the above gets ignored by the system.

[image]

Comment: And what if it doesn't have default style...?

Comment: If it doesn't have default style, setting the font as above gets ignored by the system

Comment: I wonder do apple do this deliberately. Thanks this helped me.

Comment: change Style from Plain to Default is saving me a lot time.  
Thanks

Comment: Thanks changing style to default helped me to change font size

Answer (score 77):

For **Swift 3.0**:

```
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
```

where "boldSystemFont" and "16" can be replaced with your custom font and size.

Answer (score 73):

#### Dot-notation is awesome

```
btn.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)
```

Comment: @mahasam UIFont is inferred, this answer is the same than the others but just without UIFont (but becasuse it is inferred by the compiler, but it is the same) P.D: I always try to write in this way, but just to let you know that is the same

Comment: @mahasam: "Dot-notation" is the same as inferred. And yes It's a good habit to adopt. And it's not the same answers as others as its more succinct than other answers. IMO

Answer (score 11):

If you need to change only size (**Swift 4.0**):

```
button.titleLabel?.font = button.titleLabel?.font.withSize(12)
```

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 5, you can utilize dot notation for a bit quicker syntax:

`myButton.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)`

Otherwise, you'll use:

`myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .medium)`

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to force unwrap the titleLabel to set it.

`myButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 20)`

Since you're not using the titleLabel here, you can just optionally use it and if it's nil it will just be a no-op.

I'll also add as other people are saying, the font property is deprecated, and make sure to use `setTitle:forControlState:` when setting the title text.

Answer (score 9):

If you are setting AttributedString to the UIButton then you can do the below thing.

```
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Calibri", size: 19)])
okayButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/font):

> The font used to display text on the button. (**Deprecated in iOS 3.0**. Use the `font` property of the [`titleLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel) instead.)

Answer (score 7):

If you're having font size issues (your font isn't responding to size changes)...

@codester has the right code:

```
myButton.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 20)
```

However, my font size wasn't changing. It turns out that I asking for a font that didn't exist ("HelveticaNeue-Regular"). It wasn't causing a crash, but seemed to be just ignoring that font statement because of it. Once I changed the font to something that does exist, changes to "size: x" did render.

Answer (score 7):

we can use different types of system fonts like below

```
myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)
myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize:UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)
myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.buttonFontSize)
```

and your custom font like below

```
    myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:12)
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4206848/754604).

You should set the font of the button's titleLabel instead.

```
myButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "...", 10)
```

Answer (score 5):

You should go through the `titleLabel` property.

`button.titleLabel.font`

The `font` property has been deprecated since iOS 3.0.

Answer (score 5):

This works in Swift 3.0:

```
btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Times New Roman", size: 20)
```

Answer (score 3):

Example:     `button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)`

- If you want to use defaul font from it's own family, use for example: **"HelveticaNeue"**
- If you want to specify family font, use for example: **"HelveticaNeue-Bold"**

Answer (score 3):

To do this using storyboard, go to the attributes inspector while your button is selected.  In the third field from the top ("Title") select "Attributed".  This will bring up the font drop-down list where you can easily change the font.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "yourCustomFont", size: CGFloat(yourFontSize))
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33746963)

Answer (score 2):

This way doesn't work now:

```
 btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:12)
```

This works:

```
 btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me, thanks. I want change text size only not change font name.

```
var fontSizeButtonBig:Int = 30
```

btnMenu9.titleLabel?.font =  .systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(fontSizeButtonBig))