# Is is possible to use an imported custom font for a button in swift UI ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm a beginner with swift and have reviewed [this site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app) to understand how importing custom fonts work. I've also reviewed [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002017/how-to-change-font-of-uibutton-with-swift) which didn't seem to solve my specific issue

Upon reviewing the site, I've added the .tts file Lovelo-Black to the project and plist.

```swift
        private let loginButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("log in", for: .normal)
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        button.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(rgbValue: 0x00FF9C,alpha: 1)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lovelo-Black") //issue here
        return button
```

Is it possible to make the button use the Lovelo-Black font? Ideally, I would like it to look like this[image: login image]

If it is possible, what should I replace the 8th line with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add the fonts correctly to your project..

[check this link](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-app-using-swift/)

Use the correct font name

[image]

> `button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lovelo Black", size: size)`

Answer (score 0):

In swiftUI you can use custom function from Font to initialise and use any custom fonts. have a look at bellow example code.

```swift
Font.custom("Lovelo_Black", size: 24)
```

Which generates bellow result